# Implementing native android .aar file or .aidl in Nativescript throws native calss object without access to methods

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-plugin

I have an Android SDk done with java whic I already converted to .aar file. I created a plugin and placed the aar file in App_Resources/Android/libs directory. In my index.js file, I have this

var intent = new android.content.Intent(application.android.foregroundActivity, com.iposprinter.printertestdemo.IPosPrinterTestDemo.class)
intent.setFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
application.android.foregroundActivity.startActivity(intent);
This cause the sdk to display.

Doing this

var iposprinter=new com.iposprinter.printertestdemo.IPosPrinterTestDemo()
console.log(iposprinter) //outputs com.iposprinter.printertestdemo.IPosPrinterTestDemo@682890e
while this `console.log(iposprinter.printerInit) outputs undefined`
while this

`console.log(iposprinter.printerInit) outputs undefined`
console.log(iposprinter.printerInit()) outputs undefined
TypeError: iposprinter.printerInit is not a function

How do I call methods from this package?

Comment: The attribute should be public in the class, did you try generating typings that might make it easier for you.

Comment: Pls how do I go about that? I am actually not realy good at that pls. Any guide doing such?

Comment: Just refer the docs for android typings section - https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/metadata/generating-typescript-declarations